# org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException

Tags: spring, web-services, rest

I get the following exception when I try to get User from my Web Service.  org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.shopping.model.User] and content type [text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1]

My User class is annotated with @XmlRootElement

Client code:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
User x = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/Online_Shopping/dispatcher/rest/hello",User.class);
```

Web Service code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
public class RESTController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", 
method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser() {
   User x = new  User("paymon","123",true); 
   HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
   return new ResponseEntity<User>(x, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: It seems your client is getting a html response from your api. Can you call your api directly from a browser? Do you get xml or html content? You can try to use getForEntity instead of getForObject and check the headers as well.

Comment: When I access the web service directly from the browser an XML representation of the object is returned.

Comment: I guess you do not have a http message converter for json registered. What do you get when calling rt.getMessageConverters() on your client?

Comment: I updated the question with my updated code, using a message converter.  Still getting the same exception.

Comment: when I call rt.getMessageConverters(), it prints out an array as follows:[org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@16e6038f, org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@103c].... , etc etc

Comment: It appears that all the message converters are automatically registered, including the Jackson one I added.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the response headers to the response entity. It is done automatically by Spring because your the mapping produces `xml`, so remove it.

[MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html)

The converter you are adding to the rest template is the one used to converts json objects. If you change your mapping to produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` you should get a json string.

You could use `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` if you want to use jackson to convert xml content.

[Rest xml response example with jackson 2](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-xml-response-example-with-jackson-2)

[Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html)

Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter is the default converter used by Spring to de/serialise Java objects to/from XML. This converter is only added if Spring find the library JAXB2 on the class path, so you need to include that dependency if you do not have it yet.

[Http Message Converters with the Spring Framework](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)

Comment: I added Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessagConverter to the converters, but still get the same exception.  Says the content type is text/html even though I specify xml.  I do not understand what you mean by adding the JAX2B dependency because I was able to import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter;

Comment: I followed the last tutorial to the letter and still get the same exception.  I don't understand why it is saying content type is text/html

Comment: Does your client have access to the service? Is the User class at your client the same that the one at your webservice? To be sure, try to get a String.class instead of a User.class from your client and print it out. Do you get a xml string or the same exception? rt.getForObject("url",String.class);

Comment: THANK YOU, I commented out the security interceptor and it works now.  Now I am just wondering how to secure the web service because I can only access it (through browser) when I am logged in.  But when I am logged in I cannot access the web service through java code.